# Is there any way to disable navbar for every markdown files under a particular subdirectory of a Vuepress project?

Tags: vuejs2, vuepress

I have a Vuepress project where I want to make navbar property false for some markdown files which belong to a particular subdirectory. I went through the Vuepress documentation where they are making navbar false for a specific page. And that works fine! But apart from going every file and adding that property to false, is there any way to write it in a single file and it will be rendered for every files under that particular subdirectory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no such way. If it isn't documented in the docs, there is no way to do it. You just have to go to every file in that directory and set that property to false.